# preg match only one line in each match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this pattern.. The matches must not cross multiple lines (there must not be any newline char in the matches) so I added the `m` modifier..

But sometimes there is a `\n` in the matches.. How to prevent this?

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\d|\d\D)(?:dk)?([\d\PL]{8,})/m', $input, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: `\D` and `\PL` match any whitespace chars. Actually, you get `\n` due to `\PL` as it is part of the consuming pattern. Note that `[\d\PL]` = `\PL`. Try replacing `([\d\PL]{8,})` with `([^\pL\r\n]{8,})`

Comment: NB: The `m` modifier is irrelevant for your search.

Comment: Unless impractical, you can explode on \n and foreach each array item then implode back.

Comment: If you have further questions regarding this same issue, please add comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\PL` pattern matches any char but a Unicode letter and also matches digits *and* whitespace chars. So, `[\d\PL]` can be shortened to `\PL` and since you need to subtract line breaks from it, replace it with the reverse shorthand character class (`\pL`) and use it inside a negated bracket expression, `[^\pL]`, and add `\r` and `\n` there:

```
'/(?<!\d|\d\D)(?:dk)?([^\pL\r\n]{8,})/u'
```

The `m` modifier is redundant since it only redefines the behavior of `^` and `$` anchors. You might need the `u` modifier though, for the Unicode property class to work safely with Unicode strings in PHP/PCRE. Change `\d` to `[0-9]` and `\D` to `[^0-9]` if you only want to match ASCII digits.